# Best way of implementing text to command (js to something)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, command, voice

So I have a system that takes voice input, and converts it into text inside Javascript for use on a HTML page.

What I want to know, is what would be the best and fastest way to implement a sort of framework or algorithm to take my Javascript value and turn it into a command to use with my application for database manipulation, or something of the sort.

For my application I have access to HTML,  Javascript, php, and a bunch of database tables.

Does anyone know the best way to implement a sort of system? Either open source framework or a way to design it myself?

Comment: Are you looking for an NLP (natural language processing) solution? e.g. Siri

Comment: Sort of, yes. I've already designed a system that takes voice input and converts it to text, I just want to find an engine of some sort to turn that spoken text into usable instructions for my program. I just don't know the best way of going about it yet.

Comment: Here's a list of some NLP APIs that are out there: http://blog.mashape.com/post/48946187179/list-of-25-natural-language-processing-apis

Comment: Thank you for the link to the list! I'll probably end up going with one of these in the end of it all. Do you have any personal experience with any of these engines by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the $.ajax() function. Using a POST function, you could send information to a PHP interface and have it work with the databases there.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2FjQuery.ajax%2F&ei=HsFrU9fjAoK_oQSN34C4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGgNuN1cNvVywWefhq2yse1KbMdaw&bvm=bv.66330100,d.cGU

Comment: That's step one! now I just need to figure out how to parse those received strings into commands within php... Any ideas?